# Proper way to create index template that is applied to all in ElasticSearch

Tags: templates, elasticsearch, indexing

I'm still new to the ElasticSearch technology and right now struggle with creating index template that will be applied to all new indices but can't create proper one.

Currently  running ElasticSearch 7.9.2 and it's documentation [index templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.9/indices-put-template.html) informs that `index_patterns` field is required and should be array of wildcards (`*` matches any string).

Naturally I have tried using `["*"]` as pattern via Kibana's console for request:

```
PUT _index_template/template_1
{
  "index_patterns": ["*"],
  "priority": 0
}
```

I've got:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "null_pointer_exception",
        "reason" : null
      }
    ],
    "type" : "null_pointer_exception",
    "reason" : null
  },
  "status" : 500
}
```

while for request that added empty `settings`:

```
PUT _index_template/template_1
{
  "index_patterns": ["*"],
  "template": {
    "settings": {
      
    }
  },
  "priority": 0
}
```

I've received:

```
#! Deprecation: index template [template_1] has index patterns [*] matching patterns from existing older templates [.monitoring-es,.triggered_watches,.management-beats,.transform-internal-005,.logstash-management,.monitoring-kibana,.kibana-event-log-7.9.2-template,.ml-config,.watch-history-11,.ml-meta,ilm-history,.monitoring-logstash,.ml-state,.slm-history,.ml-inference-000002,.monitoring-beats,.monitoring-alerts-7,.ml-anomalies-,.watches,.ml-notifications-000001,.transform-notifications-000002,.ml-stats] with patterns (.monitoring-es => [.monitoring-es-7-*],.triggered_watches => [.triggered_watches*],.management-beats => [.management-beats],.transform-internal-005 => [.transform-internal-005],.logstash-management => [.logstash],.monitoring-kibana => [.monitoring-kibana-7-*],.kibana-event-log-7.9.2-template => [.kibana-event-log-7.9.2-*],.ml-config => [.ml-config],.watch-history-11 => [.watcher-history-11*],.ml-meta => [.ml-meta],ilm-history => [ilm-history-2*],.monitoring-logstash => [.monitoring-logstash-7-*],.ml-state => [.ml-state*],.slm-history => [.slm-history-2*],.ml-inference-000002 => [.ml-inference-000002],.monitoring-beats => [.monitoring-beats-7-*],.monitoring-alerts-7 => [.monitoring-alerts-7],.ml-anomalies- => [.ml-anomalies-*],.watches => [.watches*],.ml-notifications-000001 => [.ml-notifications-000001],.transform-notifications-000002 => [.transform-notifications-*],.ml-stats => [.ml-stats-*]); this template [template_1] will take precedence during new index creation
{
  "acknowledged" : true
}
```

Response depends only on existence of empty `template.settings` it seems like it might be slightly bugged.

Nevertheless latter approach seems to work however deprecation warning sounds dangerous and discouraging (I've tried setting priority to 0 but to no avail). However [Documentation of 6.8](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/indices-templates.html#multiple-templates) version sports example of `"*"`. So such functionality existed not long ago.

What is the proper way, if there is one, to construct "match all" index template?

Comment: Can you mention the post paylaod on the question itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently to match all indices you really need to use the `*` as the index pattern and the warning is there because it will match anything, including the internal systems indices.

Depending on what is in your template this can lead to things not working right or break your system.

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/38678) on github about it, mostly regarding to the `.security` index, which is also affected when you use an match all index pattern, and there is another [open issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/50251) that also deals with this problem.

Comment: Thank you, it seems I would need to settle on some prefixed pattern.